# How can I return this data with a min and max column replacing the allyears column and excluding the rows which are the same in all other aspects?

Tags: sql, range, max, min

I have this data in a temp table:

```
StockID SKU Type    Id  Make    Model   Variant CC  AllYears
000164  JTR16.40                        36  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     125 1988
000541  JTR5.41                         1789    Aprilia ETX Tuareg  125 1985
000541  JTR5.41                         1789    Aprilia ETX Tuareg  125 1986
000541  JTR5.41                         1789    Aprilia ETX Tuareg  125 1987
000543  JTR5.43                         24  Aprilia     Pegaso  600 1990
000543  JTR5.43                         24  Aprilia     Pegaso  600 1991
000543  JTR5.43                         24  Aprilia     Pegaso  600 1992
000543  JTR5.43                         24  Aprilia     Pegaso  600 1993
000543  JTR5.43                         38  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     600 1990
000543  JTR5.43                         38  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     600 1991
000543  JTR5.43                         38  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     600 1992
000543  JTR5.43                         33  Aprilia SPX Tuareg Paris Dakar  600 1988
000543  JTR5.43                         33  Aprilia SPX Tuareg Paris Dakar  600 1989
000543  JTR5.43                         33  Aprilia SPX Tuareg Paris Dakar  600 1990
```

I want to get it in this format:

```
StockID SKU Type    Id  Make    Model   Variant CC  YearFrom    YearTo
000164  JTR16.40                        36  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     125 1988    1988
000541  JTR5.41                         1789    Aprilia ETX Tuareg  125 1985    1987
000543  JTR5.43                         24  Aprilia     Pegaso  600 1990    1993
000543  JTR5.43                         38  Aprilia     Tuareg Wind     600 1990    1992
000543  JTR5.43                         33  Aprilia SPX Tuareg Paris Dakar  600 1988    1990
```

I tried using min but don't think I was doing it correctly.

Comment: What's the expected result if there are gaps for a model? (E.g. 1990 and 1992, but not 1991?)

Comment: That would be
1990 1990
1992 1992

I'm pretty sure that won't be present in the data.